# Catching a Promise rejection error with an Observable in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I've been trying to unit test the handling of an error from an Observable that is wrapping a Promise, and I can't seem to get it to catch the error at all.
I'm setting up an observable from a promise that will just reject, and then I return that from the spyOn.  This works for a correctly resolving promise, but on rejection, I get the error: 'Error: Uncaught (in promise): error'

My code:

```
   it(
  'should not change status if unsucessful',
  fakeAsync(() => {

    const obs = from(
      new Promise(resolve => {
        return Promise.reject('error');
      })).pipe(catchError( (error) => {
        console.log('oh no');
        return of(error);
      }));

    spyOn(
      mockService,
      'ChangeStatusToAvailable'
    ).and.returnValue(obs);
    component.SetStatusToAvailable();
    tick(200);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log(component._status);
    expect(component._status).toBe(AgentStatus[AgentStatus.disconnected]);
  })
);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Promise` is built incorrectly.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> executor
>   A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is called before the Promise constructor even returns the created object).
>   ... The return value of the executor is **ignored.**

And in anycase, you don't need to manually construct the promise (that's actually an anti-pattern). Try:

```
const obs = from(Promise.reject('error'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but constructing the promise is just for visibility as this is just for unit tests/mocks, and will be refactored once it's working properly.  The non-unit test observables are wrapping SignalR promises.

Changing to const obs = from(Promise.reject('error')); makes no difference - the error is still uncaught by the observable.

Comment: Did you keep our remove the `pipe`?

Comment: Fixed it by not bothering with the damn promise.  Just creating an observable like :   const obs = throwError(new Error('test error'));